# R shiny async error later: exception occured while executing callback

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny

I am trying to built an async app using shiny and ran into a problem. Sometimes when starting the app, an error message appears in the console: "*later: exception occured while executing callback: Evaluation error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.*". The app runs as expected even when the message appears. My best guess is that it is some sort of race problem since it only appears about 50% of the times I start the app.
Thank you very much for your help and insights! Also, if you detect any other problems with my shiny implementation, feel free to let me know!

````
```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

plan(multisession) # plan(multicore) -> forking (not Windows/RStudio)



scopes_ui <- c('a', 'b', 'c')


ui <- function(){
  tagList(
    
    # numeric input for the first promise
    numericInput(inputId = 'num1',
                 label = 'Choose your first number: ',
                 value = 0,
                 min = 0,
                 max = 10),
    
    # numeric input for the second promise which relies on the first promise
    numericInput(inputId = 'num2',
                 label = 'Choose your second number: ',
                 value = 3,
                 min = 0,
                 max = 10),
    
    # input to test additional filter options
    selectInput('ui_scope',
                label = 'Choose scope: ',
                scopes_ui,
                selected = 'a'),
    
    # this will receive the output of the future
    h2('1. Table'),
    tableOutput('res1'),
    
    h2('2. Table'),
    tableOutput('res2'),
    
    # this plot will be drawn before the future is resolved
    plotOutput('plot_inst'),
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # empty list sufficient (no need to actually initiate with NULLs)
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    last_id1 = NULL,
    res1 = NULL,
    res1_id = NULL,
    value1 = NULL,
    scope = NULL,
    last_id2 = NULL,
    value2 = NULL,
    res2 = NULL
  )
  
  
  # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #
  #  First promise       #
  # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #
  observe({
    
    # initiate reactive variables BEFORE the promise
    rv$last_id1 <- glue('ID_{input$num1}')
    last_id1 <- rv$last_id1

    rv$value1 <- input$num1
    value1 <- rv$value1

    rv$scope <- input$ui_scope
    scope <- rv$scope
    
    
   # promise
    future_promise({
      
      # make computation expensive
      if(value1 %% 2 == 0) {
        Sys.sleep(10)
      }

      data <- data.frame(treat = c('a', 'b', 'c'), outcome = c(value1, 1.9, 3.2))
      data <- data %>% filter(treat == scope)

      # return id and data from the future
      list(
        id = last_id1,
        res = data
      )
    }) %...>%
      (function(result){
        # change value1 of `rv$res1` only if the current id is the same as the last_id
        if (result$id == rv$last_id1){
          rv$res1_id <- result$id
          rv$res1 <- result$res
        }
      })

    # this must return something (including "empty") to execute asynchronously
    return()
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$num1, input$ui_scope)
  
  
  # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #
  #  Second promise      #
  # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #
  observe({
    
    # initiate reactive variables BEFORE the promise
    rv$last_id2 <- glue('ID_{input$num1}_{input$num2}')
    last_id2 <- rv$last_id2
    
    rv$value2 <- input$num2
    value2 <- rv$value2
    
    # ensure that rv$res1 is available
    data <- req(rv$res1)
    
    # promise
    future_promise({
      
      # make computation expensive
      Sys.sleep(5)
      
      data[1,2] <- value2
      
      # return id and data from the future
      list(
        id = last_id2,
        res = data
      )
    }) %...>%
      (function(result){
        # change value of `rv$res2` only if the current id is the same as last_id2
        if (result$id == rv$last_id2){
          rv$res2 <- result$res
        }
      })
    
    # this must return something (including "empty") to execute asynchronously
    return()
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(rv$res1, input$num2)



  # output$res1 will be printed whenever rv$res1
  # is available, i.e. returned from the future,
  # and corresponds to the last input sent.
  output$res1 <- renderTable({
    req(rv$res1)
  })
  
  output$res2 <- renderTable({
    req(rv$res2)
  })

  # output$plot_inst will be drawn immediately
  my_plt <- reactive({
    data <- data.frame(treat = c('a', 'b', 'c'), outcome = c(1, 2, 3)) %>%
      filter(treat == input$ui_scope)
    ggplot(data, aes(treat, outcome)) +
      geom_col() +
      theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
    })
  
  output$plot_inst <- renderPlot({
    req(my_plt())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````